# How to avoid creating an intermediate data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am working with a dataset where I need to identify the max date difference between multiple duplicate rows. The code I have below works to satisfy my requirements (minus the "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" warning I get), but I am curious about how to perform the same task without having to create a new dataframe as an intermediate. I anticipate this is good practice to avoid memory constraints, however, I am having a difficult time figuring out this type of flow. Any guidance would be very helpful!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['10003', '10009', '10009', '10009', '10009','10034','10034', '10034'], 
               'Num1': [12,13,13,13,13,14,14,14],
               'Num2': [121,122,122,124,125,126,127,128],
              'Date1': [20120506, 20120506, 20120506,20120506,20120620,20120206,20120206,20120405],
              'Date2': [20120528, 20120507, 20120615,20120629,20120621,20120305,20120506,20120506]})


df_dup = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Key', 'Num1','Num2','Date1'],keep=False)]
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Key','Num1','Num2','Date1'],keep=False)
df_dup['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dup['Date2'], format='%Y%m%d')
df_dup['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dup['Date1'], format='%Y%m%d')
df_dup['DateDiff'] = (df_dup['Date2'] - df_dup['Date1']).dt.days
df_dup = df_dup.sort_values('DateDiff', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['Key','Num1','Num2','Date1'])
df = pd.concat([df,df_dup])
```

Steps of my code:

- 1a. find all duplicated rows and store in df_dup
- 1b. remove duplicate rows in original df
- 2 In df_dup, convert date fields to datetime for comparison
- 3 In df_dup, create new column for the difference in dates
- 4 keep only the max 'DateDiff' row
- 5 Finally, concatenate both df and df_dup

The final result is one less row than the original df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want working only with rows filtered by boolean mask `m`:

```
m = df.duplicated(subset=['Key', 'Num1','Num2','Date1'],keep=False)

d1 = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[m, 'Date2'], format='%Y%m%d')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[m, 'Date1'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['DateDiff'] = (d1 - d2).dt.days
m1 = (df.loc[m, :]
        .sort_values('DateDiff', ascending=False)
        .duplicated(subset=['Key','Num1','Num2','Date1'])
        .reindex(df.index, fill_value=False))

df = df[~m1]
print (df)
      Date1     Date2    Key  Num1  Num2  DateDiff
0  20120506  20120528  10003    12   121       NaN
2  20120506  20120615  10009    13   122      40.0
3  20120506  20120629  10009    13   124       NaN
4  20120620  20120621  10009    13   125       NaN
5  20120206  20120305  10034    14   126       NaN
6  20120206  20120506  10034    14   127       NaN
7  20120405  20120506  10034    14   128       NaN
```

Comment: Very close, but since index 1 and index 2 are duplicates (based on the 4 columns) then I want to retain only one row where the datediff is greatest. If datediff is the same, then either row would suffice. In this situation, index 1 should be eliminated.

Comment: I just realise it, give me a sec.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This is very helpful!

Comment: hi @jezrael , could you pls check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860471/how-to-re-order-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-dictionary-condition

Comment: @pyd - `ram,cricket` is `1+1=2` ?

Comment: Yes @jezrael I am arranging the df based on the total value in the key comum