# how to re order a pandas dataframe based on a dictionary condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, data-analysis

I have a df like this,

```
    case        step    deep                   value
0   case 1      1       ram in India           ram,cricket
1   NaN         2       ram plays cricket       NaN
2   case 2      1       ravi played football   ravi
3   NaN         2       ravi works welll        NaN
4   case 3      1       Sri bought a car       sri
5   NaN         2       sri went out            NaN
```

and a dictionary, `my_dict = {ram:1,cricket:1,ravi:2.5,sri:1}`

I am trying to re-order the dataframe according to the values of the dictionary, I achieved this dictionary using tfidf method. I face difficulty in re-ordering as we need to re-order the rows including with the values.

My expected output is,

```
    case        step    deep                   value
2   case 2      1       ravi played football   ravi
3   NaN         2       ravi works welll        NaN
0   case 1      1       ram in India           ram,cricket
1   NaN         2       ram plays cricket       NaN
4   case 3      1       Sri bought a car       sri
5   NaN         2       sri went out            NaN
```

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post all relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex` for sorting, only is necessary values from column `value` are in `my_dict`:

```
my_dict = {'ram':1,'cricket':1,'ravi':2.5,'sri':1}

#create DataFrame from value column, replace and sum columns
a = df['value'].str.split(',', expand=True).replace(my_dict).sum(axis=1)
#create groups
b = df['step'].diff().le(0).cumsum()
#create Series by summing per groups
c = a.groupby(b).transform('sum')
#create MultiIndex
df.index = [c,b]
print (df)
            case  step                  deep        value
    step                                                 
2.0 0     case 1     1          ram in India  ram,cricket
    0        NaN     2     ram plays cricket          NaN
2.5 1     case 2     1  ravi played football         ravi
    1        NaN     2      ravi works welll          NaN
1.0 2     case 3     1      Sri bought a car          sri
    2        NaN     2          sri went out          NaN
```

---

```
#sorting MultiIndex and removing
df = df.sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     case  step                  deep        value
0  case 2     1  ravi played football         ravi
1     NaN     2      ravi works welll          NaN
2  case 1     1          ram in India  ram,cricket
3     NaN     2     ram plays cricket          NaN
4  case 3     1      Sri bought a car          sri
5     NaN     2          sri went out          NaN
```

Comment: how to add ignore case if `my_dict has Sri` it should match with `
`"sri" in df[value] `

Comment: There not exist ignoring case, need convert to lowercase `my_dict = {'Ram':1,'cricket':1,'ravi':2.5,'sri':1}
d = {k.lower():v for k, v in my_dict.items()}`

Comment: and then `a = df['value'].str.split(',', expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()).replace(my_dict).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: okay @jezrael , actually `my_dict` will always be lower, but df.value will have caps letter too. I will convert df.value to lowercase

Comment: Hi @jezrael, If we convert df["value"] to lower() it is not matching, my a gives `1,0,0,0,...` pls check once

Comment: I test it again and change in first row sample `ram` to `RAM`. Then need `my_dict = {'Ram':1,'cricket':1,'ravi':2.5,'sri':1} 
d = {k.lower():v for k, v in my_dict.items()}
a = df['value'].str.lower().str.split(',', expand=True).replace(d).sum(axis=1)`